# Dynamic array with dynamic number of variables with dynamic variable names

Tags: c#, dynamic, arraylist, ado.net, dynamic-arrays

I have two sql Datareaders . 1st Data reader  with fixed number of columns and  fixed column names.2nd Data reader with dynamic number of columns with dynamic names. How can I combine data from two result sets in a single array list. I need to use this array list to brind values to jqgrid.

1st result set from sql

```
RequestNumber| OrderedQty | ReceivedQty 
101             100              90
102             500              420
103             10               10
```

2nd result set from sql

```
RequestNumber |BrokenKnobs| BrokenLens| WaterDamaged
101             10             9             10
102             5              4             4
103             1              1             4


RequestNumber |BrokenConnector| MissingComponents
104            10               9            
105             5               4             
106             1               1
```

For all requests , 1st result set has same number of columns and same column name. 
2nd result set changes depending on input values. Number of columns and column name both changes with every input with request number column remains same for all requests.

Comment: have you tried [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx)?

Comment: No, Can you please tell me how can I do it with LINQ

Comment: What linq is is a quering language, you can query and combine results from different list. can you post your code?